# Spawning a background thread in tomcat web service

Tags: java, tomcat

i have created a SOAP webservice which calls 3-4 other web servcies. My service has to respond back within 30 seconds. The other webservices that i call takes more than 30 seconds occasionally but they usually succeed and i cant set a timeout on them and consider them failed.

I am thinking of sending a successful response in any case, and creating a background thread to call the other 3-4 web services.

How much feasible solution is this?
Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a solved problem - but the precise answer depends on how you've built your webservice.

Google "Asynchronous web service" plus whatever framework you've used to build your SOAP web service. Note - this may require you to modify your web service too.

Spawning threads within a web application is nearly always a terrible idea - a small oversight in your code (e.g. not dealing nicely with time outs) means your site runs out of threads under very moderate load, and your site becomes extremely brittle. Much better to use an off-the-shelf solution...